# DOM Navigation - Use parent or getById?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Should I prefer :

```
$(this).parent().parent().action();
```

Or :

```
$('#idOfBlock').action();
```

*Use case* :
In a page, I have several div generated, each containing buttons and display zones. Since they are closely related, I thought about using *parent()* would be better since it only navigates within the concerned div.
However I am calling this function twice, and I start to wonder if *selectById* isn't a better idea. It's only one function call, but it searches my block ID through all the DOM tree, so isn't that more work ?

**EDIT** : I have no duplicate ID on the page.

**EDIT2** : http://jsfiddle.net/nightbaron/0ejL5p3n/3/
 - **HTML Output** (the skeleton is auto-generated so I know it's ugly, but I can't edit it. I can just do the binding).

Comment: Do you have `idOfBlock` unique on page

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs?

Comment: Assuming the `id` is unique, use that selector as it's by far the quickest. If you need to traverse the DOM to find an element dependant on the one which raised an event, use `parent()` or any of the other traversal methods.

Comment: Actually, the id is always unique but for `#widget-123-button`, I have to toggle `#widget-123-text`.

So I have to use `$(this).attr('id')`, then parse the id to get "text" instead of "button", then bind the action.

That's why it looks so complicated to me this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution is a better idea : imagine later on you decide to change your page architecture, then `.parent().parent()` might not point to the right block!

Comment: Since that is what is actually going to happen to the code, this made me take a decision. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, You should have unique id on one page, So you can use `$('#idOfBlock').action();`

Comment: I do have a unique id for each block. But retrieving this id without using parent() might be troublesome. I commented on question to add missing details about the use case.